# Mapping a "Num Lock" key on a French laptop keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, autohotkey, capslock, azerty-keyboard

I have a laptop on Windows 10 with a french "AZERTY" keyboard. It is a 14" laptop, so there isn't a number pad on the right of the keyboard, the numbers are only on the North of the letters.

The number keys are also used to write common accentuated letters (e.g. the "2" key writes an "é" when typed). To have the key write a number instead, I have to either hold Shift while typing it, or have caps lock engaged.

The problems with this are that:

- It is not possible to write a capital accentuated letter, since typing caps lock or holding down Shift will write a number. This is bothering when writing a sentence in French.
- There is no way of typing numbers "naturally" without having the letters be capitalized. This is bothering when coding.

What I would like to do to solve this are two things:

- Modify the action of Caps Lock so that typing "é" with caps lock on writes a capitalized "é" instead of a "2".
- Map a key that I don't use to engage a "Num Lock" when typed, so that typing the number keys actually writes the numbers, but having that "Num Lock" key engaged doesn't change anything else (so the letters aren't capitalized).

I have tried using AutoHotKey to do it, but I don't understand how having keys toggled works. Any tips on that would help me a lot.

Basically, what I want to do would be:

- If Caps Lock is toggled on then pressing a number key writes the capitalized accentuated letter.
- If New Num Lock is toggled on then pressing a number key writes that number. Pressing a letter key writes the letter not accentuated.

Do you know how I could do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the code you tried?